# Eval method Watson conversation?

Tags: javascript, spring-el, watson-conversation

I have another question for Watson Conversations experts ;) I have a new problem. I need to evaluate a string to a variable name : I create 4 static values :

```
{ "Pmarguerita": 9,
    "Pregina": 10,
    "Pcarne": 10,
    "PEVEA": 12
}
```

When I parse user's input, I concatenate like this :

```
{
"PiPrice": "<? 'P'+entities['name_pizza'][0].value ?>"
"total" :"<?entities['sys-number'][0].value.toInt() * eval(PiPrice) ?>"
}
```

But Eval function is not recognized and I can't find any doc allowing a variable value to be evaluated to a variable name's value like in python :

```
a = 3
b ='a' 
print(eval(b))
3
```

I could do a if elif look-a-like block with multiple nodes, but if the user's input starts to be important, the number of nodes it would require would become exponentially huge.
Is there a way to use this in the app.js src code you can find in the App builder Pipeline ?

Answer (score 1):

I tested something similar and came up with the following workaround:

- I split the node in two, each using one evaluation (`<? ?>`)
- The first node has an empty output, but sets a context variable to the evaluated value. The node is configured to jump to another node (the second node).
- The second node has the final evaluation and generates the output (response).

Answer (score 0):

While @data_henriks answer is the correct way to do it in Conversation, sometimes you need to do this at the application layer.

So you would return your values for each item as a context variable, then create a context variable like `"run_eval"` and have it's value match the eval statement you want to execute using the context variable names. With a set context variable for return value.

For example:

```
"context": {
  "Pmarguerita": 9, 
  "Pregina": 10,
  "Pcarne": 10,
  "PEVEA": 12,
  "PiPrice": "<? 'P'+entities['name_pizza'][0].value ?>",
  "Items": "<?entities['sys-number'][0].value.toInt() ?>"
  "run_eval" : "$PiPrice * $Items",
  "run_eval_return_field": "total"
}
```

At your application layer, you would parse out the `run_eval` so you would end up with something like (5 items, $10 each).

```
10 * 5
```

Then eval() that, and return to conversation something like the following:

```
"context": {
  "Pmarguerita": 9, 
  "Pregina": 10,
  "Pcarne": 10,
  "PEVEA": 12,
  "PiPrice": "10",
  "Items": "5"
  "total": "50"
}
```

It goes without saying you need to handle the dangers of running eval.